# Get a JSON Keyword out of an Array

Tags: java, arrays, json

Got a little Problem;

il receive a JSON lost array from https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/yeroise
and i want the keyword "viewers"    (From stream.viewers).

So how do i write this command then since the one below doesnt work;

```
json.get("stream.viewers")
```

Full Code;

```
private String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }



  public void StreamChecker() throws IOException, JSONException {
    json = readJsonFromUrl("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+ownerchannel);
    System.out.println(json.get("stream.viewers"));
```

Comment: Can you add the the relevant code to your question?

Comment: Is it google GSON or org.json.*?

Comment: its the org.json package.

Comment: Tell if my solution solved your problem, it should, at least.

Comment: Give me a sec, testing it right away =)

Comment: Yes its working. another question; if i want to get a object even deeper, (stream.channel.views) how would it be written then? =))

Comment: the same way - walk through json tree until you hit data you're looking for. Spend a few minutes reading API, it is fairly simple and provide all you need to get any common type of data from your JSON. http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html.
Exactly for `stream.channel.views` you need to retrieve JSONObject `stream` first, then take JSONObject `channel` _from_ `stream` and then take your primitive `views`. I will leave the exact code for you, I belive it is fairly easy to do if you understood the general idea.

Comment: I would suggest you to format your JSON using http://json.parser.online.fr/, for instance, it makes it much easier to read your JSON and find exact route to desired data.

Comment: Ok got it. so its json.getJSONObject("stream").getJSONObject("channel").getInt("followers"));   Really easy to udnerstand. Thank you alot! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Ive downloaded a JSON Viewer Extension so i dont need the parser site. =)

Comment: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/yeroise/follows/ Can some1 check the JSON url above? i need the path to the "follows" object but im unable to reach it. idk :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get `stream.viewers` instead of getting `viewers` inside of `stream` object so you need to receive `stream` as separated json object and then get `viewers` field.

If you're using Google GSON:

```
json.getAsJsonObject("stream").getAsInt("viewers");
```

In case of `org.json.*`:

```
json.getJSONObject("stream").getInt("viewers");
```